# How do I set Google Chrome to close when I swipe away the last tab?

Tags: applications, chrome-for-android

On another device, when I swipe away chrome's last open tab, the whole app closes. I don't know how I got it to do that.

Answer (score 4):

On newer Chrome versions, to get the app to close itself when you close tha last tab, setting homepage on is not enough. When you set homepage on, you get to choose between:

- Chrome's homepage
- (enter custom web adress)

The trick is to select the second option and leave it blank!

Answer (score 1):

This is automatic for Google Chrome, if it has no tabs open then it closes everything, I know it's annoying, and there's a fix. Go into the top bar, settings, and the 7th option or so should be called Home page. Turn this off and it won't happen again.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Regards

Comment: Look like this is basically the same answer as the [existing answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/185533/44325), which OP also stated that they didn't see the Homepage setting.

Comment: It is similar to the existing answer, but more detailed, and I am a newbie, I can't edit other people's answers

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that will only happen if you have home page enabled. 
Open chrome, open menu>settings>home page>on.

Comment: I don't have homepage option on the other device, how do I enable it?

Comment: So device 1 closes the chrome app when the last tab is closed and device to doesn't correct? (I'm giving them numbers so i can understand what you mean when you say 'other'. When you go into chrome and press the menu (three dots on the top right) then press 'settings' in settings the 4th option should be 'home page' open it and select 'on'. You can change the page that should open first to any website you want. I have it set on Google.com. don't you have that option in settings on phone 2?

Comment: If the home page option is not there, can you tell me what phone you have?

Comment: Yeah I don't have the homepage option, ASUS Zenfone 2

Comment: Try this: Go to the top right of the browser, select the menu > Settings > Appearance. Check the box next to "Show Home Button," and then Change. Type www.google.com in the text box, click OK, and close and open the browser to see the new homepage.

Comment: These are the only options I see https://i.imgur.com/Cv6gmvK.jpg

Comment: Strange. I couldn't find anything online as to why homepage option might be missing. Make sure you're using the latest version of chrome, also try deleting data of the app (settings>apps>chrome>storage>manage data>clear data.) That should delete any of your saved history or anything as long as you're signed into an account. If you're not signed in, try signing in and see if home page shows up. To sing in, search anything in Google, now go all the way down on the results page and sign in.

Comment: Well it should've signed in when I connected Google account to the phone itself but anyway, my research has pretty much just summed up as "it's like that on some phones for some reason". Which was why I asked here, to see if somebody knows an unorthodox approach to enabling it. I guess it will remain a mystery.